# MySql Clauses Execution order and Logical order?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, clause

I want to know what's the order of execution order of MySql clauses also the logical order of MySql clauses.

Comment: Please explain the "logical order of MySQL clauses".

Comment: Maybe show us a query about which you have a doubt.  I don't think the "logical" and "execution" orders should be any different.

Comment: Are you talking about how expressions are evaluated? Like MDAS in math? (*M*ultiplication and *D*ivision then *A*ddition and *S*ubtraction) Or something else?

Comment: With Logical Order I mean the order of all clauses when I write a query:
(ex): 
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=10;

here the first is SELECT the second is FROM and so on. 

The Execution order is the order of clauses that get executed by DBMS(I think the FROM clause is executed first!)

So I want to get the order of all clauses, the logical and execution order.
Thank you!